# How to establish Segue connection between two table views via swift in the root table view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to establish a connection between my masterTableViewController and dataTableViewController from my masterTableViewController.swift file. I am able to establish the connection in storyboard but not able to establish the logic in swift. please assist.

Below is the code which i wanted to convert to swift :-

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryBoardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isequalToString:@“state”]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        StateTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.countryname = [countries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.title = destViewController.countryname;
    }
}
```

From the above i wish to get the country name from the roottableviewcontroller and then depending on the name of the country, i wish to access the states which i have put in an array for that country in my StateTableViewController. But not able to achieve it.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. "Establishing a connection" isn't helpful - what do you actually want to _do_?

Comment: Based on a cell pressed on my root tableviewcontroller i want to display the information associated to that cell in the next tableviewcontroller. For eg , If my root tableviewcontroller displays the list of all the countries and if i press a cell associated to one country then the control should transition to the next tableviewcontroller to display the state's associated to that country. I am able to achieve it in objective C , However wanted to understand how can same be achieved via Swift.

Comment: So your question is about converting objective-c code to swift? In that case, include the code in your question and highlight the parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: Edit the question, code is too hard to read in comments. There's an edit link underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent Swift code for your Objective-C code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "state" {
        // indexPathForSelectedRow() returns an optional indexPath.  Here I use
        // optional binding to unwrap it
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as StateTableViewController
            destViewController.countryname = countries[indexPath.row]
            destViewController.title = destViewController.countryname
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, But do I need to declare destViewController somewhere as it gives me an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'destViewController'" . ??

Comment: Yes you are right. I just got it thanks.. also i did a small modification listed as above.

Comment: Let's first establish a few things.  Put a `println("in prepareForSegue")` before the first `if`.  Put a `println("inside if let")` after the `if let` statement.  Try hardcoding `destViewController.countryname = "France"`.

Comment: Yes, I did similar to what you mentioned above and identified that the control was not going inside the If logic. Then i just renamed segue identifier connection to States and also updated the if condition to  segue.identifier == "States". It worked, I am not sure why it didn't worked initially with state. Also I think countries[indexPath.row] should be changed to countries.indexPath.row for swift.  I tried to edit your post but it seems it was rejected.

Comment: Firstly, I really appreciate your active involvement in assisting me on all my queries :). Now I am able to display the list of all the countries in my first table view controller and then when i select/press a country the control takes me the next table view controller where it displays the associated states. Having done all that, now I want to display a pdf file as associated with a state when a state is pressed. Any idea/example on how can i achieve it in swift. Also I want to go back to the states table view from my pdf view.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to display a PDF file.  Search Stack Overflow and Google.  If you can't find anything, ask a new question.  If your table view is in a Navigation controller and you use a push segue to transition to it, you should have a back button that takes you back to the previous ViewController which would be your States table view controller.